# How can I properly display this enumeration type?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int Rows = 5;
const int Cols = 5;
```

Is this the proper way of declaring enums and using them?

```
enum Minesweeper { Mine = '@', Blank = '*', Loss = 'X'};

void StudentInfo ( );
void Information ( );
void make_board (Minesweeper Board [][Cols], int Rows, int mines);

int main ( )
{
        StudentInfo ( );

        Minesweeper Board [Rows][Cols];
        int mines = 0;

        cout << "       Enter amount of mines (5 - 10): ";
        cin  >> mines;

        Information ( );

        make_board (Board, Rows, mines);


        return 0;
}
```

How can I make this function out put the initialized character rather than outputting an integer?

```
 void make_board (Minesweeper Board [][Cols], int Rows, int mines)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
                {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
                        {
                                Board [i][j] = Blank;   // outputs the integer 42
                                cout << Board [i][j] << ' ';

                        }
                cout << endl;
                }

                return;
        }
```

This is the output that I am currently getting

```
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cout << static_cast<char>(Board [i][j]) << ' ';
```

Comment: it just worked, the reason why I didn't use it earlier is because it kept giving me an error saying that I couldn't convert enum to char. i probably just wrote something wrong. thanks for the help.